# Distinct and Non distinct in single mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Is there a way in mongodb to run a similar(MYSQL) query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(first_name)), COUNT(first_name) FROM table1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
db.col.find({}).count()
db.col.find({first_name: {$exists: true}}).count()
db.col.distinct('first_name').length
```